# Lucene search ton of names

Tags: lucene, keyword-search, booleanquery

I was trying to Search ton of names(10000+) against lucene index, the names were loaded from a text file. 
This is snippet of my code:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
MultiFieldQueryParser mParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(arrSearchFields,
  analyzer);

Query keyWordsQuery = mParser.parse(names);
```

- First I get the error: too many boolean clauses
    at 
  org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:118)

as search on the internet, I can fix the by

BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

But the search is slow and use a lot of memory.

Any suggestions for this case?

Appreciate it.

James

Comment: What do you have in the `arrSearchFields` and `names` variables?

Comment: what's inside your index?

Comment: I am using lucene to build the index;   arrSearchFields  is a array to hold multiple fields like body, attachment

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I hope someone finds this useful.

With Lucene 8.6.1, you can avoid "Too Many Clauses" exception by using the below query

```
(field1: term1 OR term2 OR .... OR term1024) OR (field1: term1025 OR trem1026 OR .... OR term2000)
```

instead of

```
field1: term1 OR term2 OR term3 OR .... OR term2000
```

Basically, just break up your query to consist no more than 1024 terms for each field at a time.

I'm not sure about memory usage or how fast this going to be but my intention was to get it working without throwing an error.

You may also want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614758/prevent-too-many-clauses-on-lucene-query), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901299/too-many-boolean-clauses-exception-in-solr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569999/lucene-net-search-booleanquerytoomanyclauses-system-error).